# Sending encrypted data between servers without SSL in Apache

Tags: php, encryption, ssl, theory, nodes

I have several independent PHP applications running on few servers. None of the servers have SSL, but I'm able to use PHP wraper for SSL. I would like to ensure all data sent between servers is safe and signed. Do I need to generate an certificate or is it enough to create public/private key everytime I send something? Is this aproach safe?

Comment: Does it actually have to be signed, or is it enough just to be encrypted?  Simple shared-key encryption would deter casual snoopers, and signing is significantly more work.

Comment: It should be signed, because servers must be sure of each-other's identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to generate an certificate or is it enough to create
>   public/private key everytime I send something?

Don't generate a public/private key every time. How would you be able to check who has control over the private key? The point of certificates is to be able to bind an identity to a public key: checking you trust the certificate and that you're willing to communicate with the identity it refers to is a necessary component to secure the communication.

From what I understand, the communication between the servers doesn't involve user interaction itself. If you control all the servers, you could give them certificates, either self-signed X.509 certificates (if you can install them all for all parties: only applicable for small numbers in practice) or your own CA (if you have OpenSSL, look into `CA.pl`, which has a man-page).

You could then sign an encrypt the content you exchange using S/MIME (there are functions available in PHP for this).

(You might also be able to achieve the same goal using PGP, using PGP keys/certificates instead.)

Answer (score 1):

If both machines have mcrypt then you could probably encrypt the text you want to send over the wire in PHP at one end and decrypt it at the other, but of course the big issue you have here is going to be key distribution.  You'd either have to pre-configure each machine with the correct key and hope nobody notices you're using the same key every time (which is bad), or you'll have to come up with some kind of way of distributing your key to the receiving machine when you send data without the key being snooped. (which is complicated).

You also mentioned signing, which is also a tricky issue.

Whilst it would in theory be possible to implement all this in PHP using an appropriate extension such as mcrypt, I honestly doubt it would be worth the effort of doing it right, which would be considerable,  You'd also just be reinventing the wheel.

SSL implements all the stuff you need already and is the accepted industry standard, if at all possible I'd strongly recommend you install it.

Comment: This could be an option, but manually entering keys isn't really user-friendly... I think I will stick with SSL.

Answer (score 1):

In a little project of mine I use Blowfish encryption for some data transfer, using the mcrypt extension that's available on most servers:

```
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'here goes a key', $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, null);
```

Decrypting goes the same way, just use mcrypt_decrypt. This is a shared key, not a public/private key system.